# Field template not being rendered

Tags: 7, entities, theming

On our company website we have a people page which amongst others has an image field called 'field_photo'

This is being rendered using the following:

```
<?php print render($content['field_photo']); ?>
```

However I need to be able to add some attributes to the img tag outputted, to do this I figured I would have to use a custom template and add in the required bits like so:

```
$item['#item']['attributes']['class'] = 'photo';
```

Problem I am having is no matter what I do, I don't seem to be able to get this to work no matter what I name the template (eg field--field_photo--image.tpl.php). I'm not used to working with Drupal at all, so any help would be great!

Ta

Comment: first of all, "class" is an array, so use $item['#item']['attributes']['class'][] = 'photo'; Second, to overwrite a field template you have to use the naming convention field--field_name--content_type.tpl.php. Letme know if this does the trick

Comment: @Robin I named the template field--field_photo--image.tpl.php but no joy.

Comment: the machinename of your content type is called "image"?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
$item['#attributes'] = array('class' => 'photo');
```